# Exception Handling on methods C#

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Let's suppose I have the following code...

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() => autobuyandsell.Discard_Players(client, this));
    if (stop == false)
    {
          await Task.Run(() => autobuyandsell.Buy_300_Players(client, this));
    }
}
catch (ExpiredSessionException ex) 
{
    relogin = true;
    b_stop.PerformClick();
 }
```

Inside autobuyandsell the ExpiredSessionException can occur as I call some methods which can throw that Exception. My question is, do I need to add another try/catch block inside the function or it's enough to handle the extern Exception?

**Answer accepted:**

As the only need of my program is to exit the method and restart some variables, eventually, I decided to use try/catch outside the method.

Comment: Well that entirely depends on what you want to happen if an exception is thrown. Do you want your (unconventionally named, btw) `Discard_Players` and `Buy_300_Players` methods to continue after the exception? If so, you'll need to catch the exceptions within those methods. Otherwise, you're fine to catch them in your calling code.

Comment: I apologize my naming mistake. I'm quite new in this area so I'll try to get good habits since the beggining. Back on my question, what I want is to exit the method once the exception is received so I guess I have to leave only the exception outside the method.

Comment: If you want this `try-catch` to handle the exception, then there is no need for an inner `try-catch` block. This will do fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will catch them as you have it just now but you won't "know" if/how much of your `Discard_Players` or `buy_300_Players` code executed, and at which point the Exception occurred, etc. which may be a bad idea.

For example if these methods persist state to disk/database you wont "know" if this happened or not.

(I keep using the quotes on "know" because I guess it would be possible to interrogate the call stack etc when catching the Exception to find out where it was raised in order to find these things out but that's going to get messy pretty quickly!)

if you catch them INSIDE the methods you can control how they are handled (perhaps undoing any data you have persisted before throwing again so you can start afresh, for example) much better.

So depending on the functionality of these two functions YOU should decide which approach works best for YOUR application